# What is the difference between organic and non-organic App installs?

Tags: ios, installation, event-tracking, flurry-analytics

I've read on different analytics website but couldn't understand the difference. Companies charge for non-organic installs so I'm worried about that before using those.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An organic install is when the user finds the app interesting or useful and downloads or buys it. A non-organic install is when the company rewards the user for installing the app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need some more explanation. I've to track the source of install from my App. For that I've to use a service like appsflyer or branch. What they meant by Non-organic? I need to know before starting whether I'll be charged or not? I'll give links to my employees for marketing and then have to track who produced how many downloads.

Comment: "Non-organic installs – installations attributed by AppsFlyer to a media source, such an integrated network, a OneLink deeplink, or attributed via other services such as TV campaign attribution" https://www.appsflyer.com/pricing/

Comment: I would think that non-organic install is thru an ad. And AppsFlyer only charges on non-organic installs. Would not make sense to charge for installs, which have been done without tapping an ad.

Comment: Thanks for information

Answer (score 3):

An organic install is when a user downloads a mobile application but didn’t tap any advertising or tracked campaign link. Basically, organic installs are those generated via app store search, top charts and featured slots (App Store Optimization).

On the opposite side, non-organic installs are those generated via tracked links (owned media or not) or advertising.

Hope this helps!